# Can I pass T to a class constructor

Tags: c#, .net, generics, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

I have a class such as:

```
public MyClass
{
   public myEnumType Status {get;set;}
   public DataTable Result{get;set;}
}
```

Because DataTables suck I want to implement an object orientated approach. However I have existing code such as:

```
public interface IData
{
  MyClass AddData(int i);
  MyClass GetData(string Tablename);
}
```

I would like to use this interface but instead of returning a DataTable I want to return an object of some sort eg/Person class.

I did think of creating a new class that inherited MyClass like so:

```
public MyInheritedClass<T> : MyClass
{
  public new T Result{get;set;}
}
```

However whenever you get data from a class that implements the interface you will have to cast the result of the methods from MyClass to MyInheritedClass. So I was wondering if there was a way of using the existing MyClass to put a constructor in that passes a generic type so I end up with something like

```
public MyClass
{
   public MyClass(T MyObjectOrientatedClass)
   {
      MyOOClass = MyObjectOrientatedClass;
   }
   public myEnumType Status {get;set;}
   public DataTable Result{get;set;}
   public T MyOOClass {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Your class `MyClass` has to be generic if you want it to have a property of generic type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C#, the types of expressions are determined by the types of their constituent pieces at compile time. This means something like your last example (where the type of the property is unknowable just by knowing the type of the class) can't work.

Imagine if that class definition compiled. Then you have this problem:

```
// What would you use as the type of this variable?
??? val = GetMyClassFromSomewhere().MyOOClass;
```

Sure you could use `object`, but then you wouldn't know anything about the property value, so you'd have to cast before you could do anything with it anyway.

---

Addressing your original issue, it is possible (with a few rough edges) to extend your existing types in a compatible fashion by deriving a new generic interface from your existing `IData` interface:

```
public interface IData<T> : IData
{
    new MyInheritedClass<T> AddData(int i);
    new MyInheritedClass<T> GetData(string Tablename);
}
```

Comment: By specifying the new keyword in IData<T> does the compiler still assume that you have implemented the IData methods and if IData had new methods added to it would IData<T> fail as not all methods have been implemented?

Comment: By saying `: IData`, all the members of `IData` are inherited. The `new` keyword allows new functions to be added that have the same signature of those from `IData` (and hide them). If you implement `IData<T>` you'd have to _explicitly_ implement the original `IData` methods also (probably just by calling the `IData<T>` methods). That's what I meant by "rough edges".

Comment: Oh ok, I did go down that route but I just thought it was a waste of code however maybe if the explicit methods just return the IData<T> it might not be too bad

Answer (score 1):

You can't refer to a generic type parameter without declaring it in the pointy brackets, so you'll either have to have a `IData<T>` and/or `MyClass<T>` type, in which case you won't need to specify it as a parameter to the constructor.

If you can't change those types you can still avoid explicit casting by using **dynamic dispatch**. Overload a method with the different subtypes and use a dynamic expression to defer the method resolution to runtime, and it'll be automatically cast to the subtype for you:

```
void DoSomethingWith(Person p) { ... }
void DoSomethingWith(AnotherClass x) { ... }

void DomSomtheingWithMyInheritedClass(MyClass x)
{
   DoSomethingWith((dynamic) x.Result);
}
```

Comment: Problem is its all in production so cannot change IData to IData<T> or MyClass to MyClass<T> unless T is somehow not a necessity so that old code will compile and new code can use the T

Comment: I added another suggestion to my answer.

Comment: I didn't think of dynamic, thanks but I would like this strongly typed

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a generic interface like

```
public interface IData<T>
{
    T AddData(int i);
    T GetData(string Tablename);
}
```

we can then even have a generic implementation:

```
public class MyGenericClass<T> : IData<T>
{
}
```

Comment: IData and MyClass are used in many places so unless T is not a necessity and old code will compile with specifying the T it would work.

Answer (score 0):

While it is a somewhat horrible idea, as long as what you wanted to put into T can be boxed into `MyClass`, you could write a method like...

```
public T GetResult<T>() where T : MyClass
{
    return (T)Result;
}
```

Pretty gross, but it would allow you to "encapsulate" the cast. In reality, though, we're talking about the difference between...

```
var result = (DerivedMyClass)obj.Result;
```

...and...

```
var result = obj.GetResult<DerivedMyClass>();
```

I'm not sure I think one of those is necessarily better than the other and would probably just stick with casts.